devtools::check() fails with "Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package", however debugging detects no issues
When checking my R package with devtools::check(), I run into this error.
══ Checking ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Setting env vars:
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_               : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_                      : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_                     : FALSE
• _R_CHECK_PACKAGES_USED_IGNORE_UNUSED_IMPORTS_: FALSE
• NOT_CRAN                                     : true
Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

However, when I run the hint, no issues are being detected.
> pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)
Your system is ready to build packages!

I don't even know how to continue debugging the problem from here.
Any ideas would be very welcome.
I am running RStudio 2024.04.1 and R-4.4.0

What OS are you using? What versions of devtools and pkgbuild do you have installed? It's much harder to help without any sort of reproducible example that we can test with.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise. I have devtools version 2.4.5 and pkgbuild 1.4.2. In the meantime, I noticed that the check works if I run it as devtools::check(cran = FALSE)

Same problem, the workaround also works for me, but it would be better to fix the issue.

@HaukeL. I found the answer by looking through the GitHub issues on the devtools repo, and searching the closed issues for the phrase "Could not find tools necessary to compile a package".  There was an old issue that mentioned installing RTools, since those are needed for package compliation.  I have that installed, but hadn't updated since 4.2, and the update fixed the problem.

Solved this by installing the latest version of RTools (44)
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools44/rtools.html
